Is pitch shifting fast enough to be done in real time?
As far as I know, the only good way to pitch-shift is to do a Fast Fourier Transform and apply a pitch shift that way. From some crude testing, the FFT took about 60 ms for 0.2 seconds of CD quality audio (in Rust on a decent laptop) which is significantly larger than the ~33 ms required for 30 fps, let alone the 17 ms for 60 fps and less for higher fpses. And to do that for a random pitch shift for an audio clip every time its played (for example a jump or attack sound effect) seems very inefficient.
Is there something I'm missing or is this really a bad thing to do when aiming for real-time?

Pitch shifting (without changing duration) is hard, but it's also not something you'd normally do for a sound effect.  What are you trying to accomplish?

@MattTimmermans basically the idea is to make sound effects more varied and less monotonous without having a limited pool of them (and also so that I don't need to source multiple sound effects for every sound effect)

Resampling at a faster or slower sampling rate, so the pitch (and duration) changes when you play them back, is easy to do in real time.  There are also many, many filtering or modulation effects that your can do in real time.  Or you can procedurally generate the sound effects from scratch and vary the parameters.

If it takes 60ms for 200ms of audio, why is this too slow? I don’t understand the problem. What FFT implementation are you using? Seems kind of slow… I measure 4us in MATLAB.

Do you really need CD quality for sound effects? Try with lower sample rates, lower bitrates. Keep in mind that a sound with a maximum frequency of, say, 5000 Hz needs a sampling frequency of 10000 to be correctly  converted
